# Can I create a custom protocol for git?

Tags: git, p2p

I'm trying to create Git over P2P. (It's crazy, I know.)

The question is simple: can I create a custom protocol for Git alternative to ssh://, git:// and http://?

Comment: Git isnt specially extensible, you'd have to dig in the source code (look for transport layer). Isn't Git already P2P?

Comment: Actually, I don't think so. [Take a look at "About GIT"](http://git-scm.com/about/distributed), it doesn't mention P2P at all. I thought I could use a DHT to store git data.

Comment: What you mean is *distributed storage*. P2P as a transport layer just means there is no one type of node that has a pre-set role different from other nodes (i.e. there is no concept of a "server" being a central connection point). In that sense, Git (being a DVCS) is already P2P all the way through.

Comment: The idea is not actually that crazy. The question is how much users will accept it (if you want it to be broadly used). To get more feedback and tips, you can try the mailing list and IRC channel (see [Community page](http://www.git-scm.com/community)).
Afaik, for transport Git just requires something trough which it can pipe input/output by normal stdout/stdin, if that's any help at all.

Comment: Uhm, well, my idea was to create a "fake transport" that instead of sending data to a server it would store them in a DHT. Is it possible? (BTW, thanks to @NevikRehnel for clearing my head ;-) )

Comment: Well, a DHT is probably not directly eligible (unless you re-implement a Git [protocol] client with a DHT backend yourself), because Git [client] needs another Git at the remote end to talk to. It doesnt just send files back and forth, but has its own application layer protocol.
For a "fake transport", you'd need a centralized entrypoint to accept Git connections, which then stores its data in a DHT -- which makes the whole idea of P2P kinda ironically destroying itself ;)

Comment: Be sure to [make some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=GitTorrent) first as you're definitely not the first possessed with an idea like this.  This topic has also been raised multiple times on the [main Git list](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git) so be sure to search its archives as well.

Comment: Thank you @kostix for your advice. MirrorSync (gittorrent 2.0) is a nice idea, but I can't find any piece of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is definitely possible. Git does support remote helpers for just that. From the `git fetch` manpage:

> When git doesn’t know how to handle a certain transport protocol, it attempts to use the remote- remote
>       helper, if one exists. To explicitly request a remote helper, the following syntax may be used:
>
> ```
> <transport>::<address>
> ```

Further information about remote helpers can be found at [the appropriate man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote-helpers.html). If that capability is not powerful enough for you (a quick scan suggests it should be), you should remember that git is open source ;).

Comment: I'm no longer sure it will be useful. However, thank you for giving the exact answer to my question!